# Why? Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget or pointer trouble?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I am trying to make a very simple Qt application that will display a table that is referenced from another class. that's it.

I have class UWRegModel, which takes a pointer to a vector of vectors as a parameter for the constructor.

When I build the vector in my main method and pass a reference, everything works fine, but I need to pass a reference to a vector that is contained in another class. This class has a method to get that pointer, but when I initialize this way,  the program crashes with the following error:

QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

I'm guessing there is some kind of problem with the reference, and that it has nothing to do with a widget being created before an application. However, there is no compile error, and that is all I'm getting.

Here is the code:

uwregmodel.h

```
#ifndef UWREGMODEL_H
#define UWREGMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

class UWRegModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    UWRegModel(QObject *parent = 0, std::vector<std::vector<int>> *uregs = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const ;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
};

#endif // UWREGMODEL_H
```

uwregmodel.cpp

```
#include "uwregmodel.h"

std::vector<std::vector<int>>* _uregs = NULL;

UWRegModel::UWRegModel(QObject *parent, std::vector<std::vector<int> > *uregs) :QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    _uregs = uregs;
}

int UWRegModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & ) const
{
    return (_uregs->at(0)).size();
}

int UWRegModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return _uregs->size();
}

std::string intToBits(int x){
    std::bitset<32> _x(x);
    return _x.to_string();
}

QVariant UWRegModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        std::string bin = intToBits((_uregs->at(index.column())).at(index.row()));

        QString res = QString::fromStdString(bin);

        return res;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

the main class

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include "uwregmodel.h"
#include "uwsimgui.h"
#include "ram.h"
#include "uwcpu.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app (argc, argv);

    UWCPU cpu(32,8,8);

    QMainWindow w;
    QTableView tableView;
    UWRegModel myModel(0,cpu.getUREGs());
    tableView.setModel( &myModel );

    QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout;
    hbox->addWidget(&tableView);

    QWidget *centralw = new QWidget;


    centralw->setLayout(hbox);
    w.setCentralWidget(centralw);
    w.show();


    return app.exec();

}
```

The UWCPU (uwcpu.cpp) class is very large, but here is the constructor and getUREGs method, only the relevant parts, I think:

```
int WORD_SIZE; //Ultraword will be WORD_SIZE^2
int NUM_BLOCKS;
int NUM_UREGS;
int NUM_REGS;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> UREG;



UWCPU::UWCPU(int _wordsize, int _uregs, int _regs){
    WORD_SIZE = _wordsize;
    NUM_BLOCKS = _wordsize;//Ultraword will be WORD_SIZE^2
    NUM_UREGS = _uregs;
    NUM_REGS = _regs;

    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_UREGS; i++){
        UREG.push_back(std::vector<int>(WORD_SIZE,0));
    }

}

std::vector<std::vector<int>>* UWCPU::getUREGs(){
    return &UREG;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck for a while and can't seem to get anywhere. I googled this pretty hard, but unfortunately it seems most people who get this error had problems with Qt libraries and versions. I don't think this is my case, I am using Qt creator, with version 5.8, and have tried running with debug and release versions and it makes no difference.

Comment: It's Qt, not QT

Comment: The code you're showing is fine. You will have to create a true, minimal example: -1. Use git or hg. 0. Create and check out a minimization branch. 1. Make a fresh build and ensure it still crashes. 2. Copy-paste all the files into `main.cpp`. 3. The file should start with `#include <QtWidgets>` and end with `#include "main.moc"`. 4. Remove any class members and functions not needed to demonstrate the issue. 5. Remove any code not needed to reproduce. 6. Move method definitions into class declarations. 7. Edit the question and insert the contents of `main.cpp` - should be <100 lines now.